# Logout of from Stack Exchange Meta or Stack Overflow results in 404 page

Tags: bug, new-nav, logout

When I log into either Meta Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow and then log out again and I end up at a 404 page.

Stack Overflow logout [goes to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&_=2040462807) and Stack Exchange Meta [ends up here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&_=56730654)

[image: Post logout screenshot]

Tried on Chrome and Firefox with the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, it is a bug... but I think it will be a no-fix.

You end-up on that specific link because the logout redirects to the last page you viewed. As you are participating in the new navigation test group you end-up as an anonymous user on the new navigation page. The anonymous user didn't sign-up for participating in the new navigation and therefor a 404 is rendered (which is by the way the default behavior for pages you don't have permissions for).

If you click on a question first and then hit logout you'll be fine...

Comment: True, I get 404 even though I'm logged in.